# Shifting by k, for large values of k (CSAPP)

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am reading about shifting by k, for large values of k in the book CSAPP. It was discussing about what would be the effects of shifting a data type consisting of w bits by some value k >= w. It stated the following line:

"On many machines, the shift instructions consider only the lower log_2 w bits of the shift amount when shifting a w-bit value, and so the shift amount is effectively computed as k mod w."

While I do understand the k mod w part, I do not understand what CSAPP means by the lower log_2 w bits of the shift amount. I was thinking that if we have an integer on a 32-bit machine that we want to shift 36 units to the left, we would shift it 36 mod 32, or 4 bits to the left. I wasn't sure how that would be equivalent to the lower log_2 32 bits = 5 bits of the shift amount.

Comment: 36 is 100100 in binary, the lowest 5 bits (log_2 of 32) are 00100 = 4